# PHP UPDATEing values through MySQL prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm sorry to post again regarding prepared statements but I'm pretty new to PHP/MySQL and totally new to prepared statements.

I have code that looks like:

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn) {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute($bindings);

//$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

  return $results ? $results : false;
}

$sitecategories = array(
0 => "Uncategorized", 10 => "Abstract", 11 => "Animals"
);

foreach ($sitecategories as $key => $value) {

  if ( $conn ) {
      $catquery=query("INSERT IGNORE into categories (cat_id, label) VALUES (:catid, :label)",
      array(':catid'=>$key, ':label'=>$value),
      $conn);
} else {
     print "could not connect to the database";
       }
}
```

Connection is elsewhere but the INSERT works fine. The resulting mysql table looks like the below (cat_id is unique):

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | cat_id | label       |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 |      0 | Uncategoriz |
|  2 |     10 | Abstract    |
|  3 |     11 | Animals     |
```

However I am trying to figure out how to create an update (for if an item is added or removed from $sitecategories).  I adapted the INSERT to

```
foreach ($sitecategories as $key => $value) {
  if ( $conn ) {
    $catquery=query("UPDATE categories SET cat_id=:catid, label = :label",
    array('catid'=>$key, 'label'=>$value),
$conn);
  } else {
    print "could not connect to the database";
  }
}
```

However when I run this I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'cat_id''
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with cat_id being unique and this issue relates not to my prepared statements but is a general MySQL syntax problem.  Any help with either would be really appreciated!

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  `cat_id` in the table is declared to be unique and you are putting duplicate values in multiple rows.  Either change the table to fit your needs (by dropping the `unique` constraint) or fix your code to work with the table definition.  There is no syntax problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I want to make sure the database contains the same values as the array.  So if an item is added to the array it should be added to the DB. If it is removed from the array it should be deleted from the DB. It is important that cat_id is unique and relates to only one label. Is UPDATE the wrong way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a WHERE clause in your update query, so it will try to change all the catid's from every record to, in this case, "0". That's why its giving you the error. It tries to set the catid the same for every record, while it has to be unique. You need to add a WHERE clause to your query, depending on which record you want to change. So like WHERE id=:id. Or WHERE catid=:catid. I don't assume you want to change every record?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the update statement you want is:

```
UPDATE categories
    SET label = :label
    WHERE  cat_id=:catid;
```

If the `:catid` may or may not be in the table, then you can use `insert . . . on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO categories(catid, label)
    VALUES (:cat_id, :label)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE label = VALUES(label);
```

Comment: Thanks again for you time.  Both of those will update the database if I add an item  to the array, but neither remove items from the database if an item is removed from the array.

Comment: @StuartBrown . . . Correct.  As I read your question, that was not in it.

Comment: Sorry, I had tried to express that in "However I am trying to figure out how to create an update (for if an item is added or removed from $sitecategories)"

Comment: @StuartBrown . . . One correct approach to do is to write functions in your code for manipulating the array (one to add an element in, one to remove an element).  *Only* use these functions.  The function maintains the array *and* the database table.

Comment: great, thanks for your advice. I'll crack on with that

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause to your query. Update command needs to know which row to be updated and you provide this detail in where clause. Adding a where clause should eliminate your error.

Refer to this document to know more about [MySQL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/) commands